# Compiling a scala class and make it available in Scala Context

Tags: scala

I have a `class` written in `Scala` and I am trying to make it available to the Scala Context so that I can make use of it for further processing. The problem is that I need to run this from the `shell` and I am having a hard time figuring out how to compile the class and make it available to the context.

I am aware of compiling the class and making use of directly, but I am not able to figure out how to do the same on the `Scala shell`. Any pointers in this regard would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Scala REPL you can use the command `:cp <path>` to add a directory or JAR (that contains your compiled Scala class) to the classpath, so that it is available for the REPL to use.

(Ofcourse, replace `<path>` in that command with the actual directory or JAR path).

To see what other commands are available in the Scala REPL, use the command `:help`.